# Symfony & Twig: how to get vars in twig by DB data?

Tags: twig

One question please.

`{{ dump(app.user.slugName) }}`

If I do the above snippet in `Twig`, I get the `slugName` of the user loged ("my-user-2", i.e.) in the app (SlugName is an atribute of the entity user). Ok & Correct. But... I want to order this action from a var (var from BD data)

I have a variable named `option` which is set like this:

`{% set option = 'app.user.slugName' %}`

But when I'm trying output this variable with `{{ dump(option)}}` it returns `app.user.slugName` as literal. It does not return `my-user-2`.

Is there are any way in `twig` to solve this? It's a function to generate a menu, but some links needs some parameters.

Comment: Then remove quotes and try again.

Comment: @u_mulder sorry, i forget say that 'app_user.SlugName' went from a BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean, but `Twig` can't evaluate expression like that.
To achieve something like that you would need a snippet like this,

```
{% set value_methods = 'app.user.slugname' %}

{% set option_value = _context %}
{% for method in (value_methods|split('.')) if method != '' %}
    {% set option_value = attribute(option_value, (method|replace({'()': '', }))) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ option_value }}
```

[twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/38k9yu)

---

*(edit)*
Remember you can create a macro to achieve some reusability for this snippet,

```
{% import _self as macros %}
{{ macros.evaluate(_context, 'app.user.slugname') }}


{% macro evaluate(context, value_methods) %}
    {% set option_value = context %}
    {% for method in (value_methods|split('.')) if method != '' %}
        {% set option_value = attribute(option_value, (method|replace({'()': '', }))) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ option_value }}
{% endmacro %}
```